# How to know the time a ECS Scheduled Task started?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a question about ECS Scheduled Task.

When I use ECS Scheduled Task scheduled by cron, how can I know the time a task started.

ECS Scheduled Tasks on Fargate takes a few minutes to launch.
I need to use accurate time every 5 minutes each.

Is there like some useful environment variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Task [metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html) has some timestamps which may be useful to you?

Comment: @Marcin I'm going to try PullStartedAt!

Comment: Thank you.
I still haven't try it. after I've got succeeded, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

A possible solution is through [task metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4.html), especially:

> **PullStartedAt** - The timestamp for when the first container image pull began.

Comment: @KoyaFukushi Glad to hear that. Thank you.